# Keyboard Interrupt not working on command prompt

Tags: python, sockets, cmd, keyboardinterrupt

I've written a simple socket server in python that listens for multiple clients until your press control c so that you can choose which client to connect to. I use error handling for keyboard interrupts but strangely keyboard interrupt does not work on my OS.

I'm using Windows 10 64 bit and running the program through command prompt yet it seems to ignore control c and z when there is a passive socket listening. I have already tried control+Fn+B but python does not recognize this as keyboard interrupt.

Is there a specific setting I need to configure for cmd to see keyboard interrupt? I tried running the program directly on the python 2.7 interpreter but keyboard interrupt is still not possible.

```
import socket,sys
try:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)#socket
        s.settimeout(10)
        s.bind(('0.0.0.0',port))
        s.listen(1)#accept max 50 connections
        while True:#locate client
            try:
                c,a=s.accept()  
            except socket.timeout:
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                print '[!]Error : '+str(e)
            if a:
                s.settimeout(None)
                time.sleep(2)
                auth=c.recv(1024)#wait 5 sec for key
                if auth == serverkey:#verify key
                    socks.append(c)
                    clients.append(a)
                    c.send('authed')
            else:#kill socket
                c.close()
                continue
            if socks:#print available clients
                clr()
                print '[*]Listening for clients...'
                clr()
                print '[ID]   |   [IP]\n==============='
                for i in range(len(socks)):#display clients
                    print '['+str(i)+']   |   ['+str(clients[i][0])+']'
                print '\nControl C to choose/quit'
    except KeyboardInterrupt:#control c for selection
        if not socks:
            sys.exit('[*]User requested shutdown...')
        elif socks:
            while True:
                id=raw_input('\n[*]ID of backdoor/-exit to quit : ')
                if id == '-exit':
                    sys.exit('\n[*]User requested shutdown...')
                else:
                    try:
                        socks[id]
                    except:
                        clr()
                        print '[ID]   |   [IP]\n==============='
                        for i in socks:
                            print '['+str(I)+']   |   ['+c(0)+']'
                        print '\n[-]Invalid ID...'
                        continue
                return id
```

its at the keyboard interrupt part where the code does not work.

Comment: Could you share your code as well? This can be OS related, but it might as well be thread management issue. It would be useful to see the program that does not work as it should.

Comment: it works on ubuntu so I doubt its thread management, in need it to run on my windows machine. I've been having trouble with keyboard interrupt for some time with all my scripts, would it be the way my cmd or system is configured?